# VueJS Primevue TreeSelect

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I put a component from **PrimeVue**: **TreeSelect** in my **VueJS** code

It works fine, but now how to know which box is selected?

```
< TreeSelect v-model="selectedNode" :options="options" selectionMode="checkbox" :metaKeySelection="false" placeholder="Select Items"> < /TreeSelect>
```

I succeed to print that:

```
{{selectedNode}}
<ul>
    <li v-for="check in selectedNode">          
        {{check}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result:

```json
{ "0": { "checked": false, "partialChecked": true }, "0-0": { "checked": true, "partialChecked": false } }

{ "checked": false, "partialChecked": true }
{ "checked": true, "partialChecked": false }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to just have the keys (0, 0-0...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response uses object keys, so you can just use those with `Object.keys`

If you're doing it in the template, just watch out for the value being null.

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="check in Object.keys(selectedNode || {})">
    {{ check }}
  </li>
</ul>
```